# bilinear map from $\mathcal{L}(E,F)\times E$ to $F$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $E,F$ two finite dimensional vector spaces and $\mathcal{L}(E,F)$ the set of linear maps from $E\to F$

and a bilinear map such as $\varphi:(L,x)\in \mathcal{L}(E,F)\times E\longmapsto \varphi(L,x)=L(x)\in F$

My question is : What is the name of this bilinear map?

Comment: You can call this the "evaluation map" or "natural pairing".

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer